# What is this go-no go function in some oscilloscopes and how can I use it?

Tags: function

I have seen some oscilloscopes with this option (go-no go function), but I don't know what it is.

I couldn't find anything about it in my searches.

What is it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See [Mask Limit Testing](http://www.picotech.com/picoscope6-mask-limit-testing.html)

> Capture a signal from a known working system, and [the oscilloscope] will draw a mask around it with your specified tolerance. Connect the system under test, and [the oscilloscope] will highlight any parts of the waveform that fall outside the mask area.

This can be used to check for intermittent problems.

[image]
<sup>*From [Agilent](http://cp.literature.agilent.com/litweb/pdf/5990-3269EN.pdf)*</sup>

Some scopes have a pass/fail output that can be used in automated testing.

[image]

Comment: I.e. a "design rule check" for your signal: something the EE can instinctively understand. :)

Comment: anybody can see different with their eyes,so why whant to use this function...?... what is sigma number on top picture

Comment: @firewhale: it's explained in the Agilent literature I linked to. *"Six Sigma mask testing"*